# Redirect Issue With Subfolder To Subdomain On Shared Host

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, shared-hosting

Heres the situation: I have a couple of different web projects running on a single shared host. **Project 'A'** is accessed through a subdomain (**subA.mydomain.com**) while **project 'B'** is the main **mydomain.com**

Both A and B are symlinks inside the host's public_html folder:

```
ln -s /home/myhost/ProjectA ~/public_html/subA
ln -s /home/myhost/ProjectB ~/public_html/main
```

The subdomain (**project A**) works fine and the site is running on it.
For **'B'** which is the main domain, i have used .htaccess to point primary domain to a subfolder as written [here](http://helpdesk.bluehost.com/index.php/kb/article/347). The domain website is also working fine.

The problem is when i do **mydomain.com/subA**, the subdomain website (**project A**) opens. I tried adding redirect rules to point ***mydomain.com/subA --> subA.mydomain.com*** like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^subA\/?$ "http\:\/\/subA\.mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

But the url still reads **mydomain.com/subA** and the website shown is project A (with images and static files missing obviously as its a different web project).

Why isn't the redirect working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following line worked (and remove the earlier regex-heavy redirection code):

```
RedirectMatch 301 /subA/ http://subA.mydomain.com/
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a `RewriteBase /` somewhere, `^subA\/?$` isn't going to match anything.  Mod_rewrite looks at the entire url, including the leading /.  Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/subA/?$ http://subA.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Also, you can loosen up on the escaping.  It doesn't hurt, but it also doesn't help anything, and it makes it harder to read.

Comment: correct, missed that, I have concentrated on the end, not on the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

request URI for mydomain.com/subA is /subA (note no trailing slash) which will not match

change your rewrite rule to

RewriteRule ^subA http://subA.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L]

Comment: hmmm...its not working. If i type "mydomain.com/subA" or "mydomain.com/subA/", the resulting url is still "mydomain.com/subA/". And i dont have anything else in htaccess besides what i mentioned in the question.

Comment: Does it matter if theres an index.php file in "subA" (i'm using frameworks), as in "/home/myhost/ProjectA/index.php"?

Comment: Should be RewriteRule ^/subA http://subA.mydomain.com/ [R=301,L], see the answer below

if it still doesnt work add

  RewriteLog   /tmp/rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 9

and post the contents of rewrite.log